# ERC721 how works setApproveForAll

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721

i do auction of nft contract. I have a complex structure:

- Contraact `Users` has array of `User` contracts, instance of `NFT` contract and instance of `Auctions` contract
- `NFt` contract has createNFT and transferNFT methods.
- `Auctions` contract has array of `Auction` contracts and methods to create new auction (`auctions.push(new Auction(some, params))`)
- `Auction` contract receives in constructor some params and tokenId of nft. And there are methods: `placeBid` and `finalizeAuction`(transfer eth to owner and transfer nft to bidder) in Auction contract
- And finally `User` contract has methods: `collectNFT` - by `nftInstance` of `Users` call createNFT and save `tokenId`. Next `createAuction` method by `auctionInstance` in Users call `createAuction`. Also, user can `placeBid` and `finalizeAuction`.

So, we have 2 users. The first creates new NFT, provide tokenId in `createAuction`. The second places a bid. Then the first finalize auction. BUT I GET ERROR - `Revert ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved`. I know what there is setApproveForAll method, but where to call it??

I don't even know why the owner is not approved!

I tried in `NFT` contract call `setApproveForAll(userAddress)`, next in `User` contract `setApproveForAll(address(auctionsInstance))`, in `Auctions` do that for `Auction` contract. But any way it is ERROR.

How is setApproveForAll works?? How to fix that? Please help me;)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code for setApprovalForAll is :

```
function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool approved) public virtual override {
    _setApprovalForAll(_msgSender(), operator, approved);
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol)

So to approve all the tokens the user who wants to approve their tokens must call the function with the parameters: user address they want to approve, and the boolean true. To revoke the permissions you must call the same function with the boolean false.

Note: the approved user is not the owner, they are simply an approvee, you can use isApprovedForAll to check if you are approved.

Comment: I try this, but something is wrong;) in `NFT` i mint nft for user address, then in `user` contract i call `nftInstance.setApprovForAll(addr, true)` - addr of userAddres, for address(this), address(auctionsInstance). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: i can't understand this system. I have userAddres (msg.sender in first called contract), throuth user contract in nft contract i mint nft to userAddress. And then approve for user contract, auctions, auction - everything! But if i call isApprovedForAll in remix for owner as userAddress, i get everywhere false! And then i think to try owner as address of user contract - everywhere true! Why??? Owner is userAddress (not user contract). i just can't understand this shit.

Comment: Are you doing approve or approveForAll?

Comment: setApproveForAll

Comment: I can add code, but it's 500 lines

Comment: put it in a pastebin

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Z8sWEhba

Comment: Okay, you do not mint to user address, you mint to the person sending the transaction and then approve the user who you are "minting" to mint to the user address you should change _mint(tx.origin, tokenCounter); to _mint(userAddress, tokenCounter);

Comment: oh, I just experimented with this yesterday) I fix this, https://pastebin.com/rTQHcLHh

Comment: ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved

Comment: so, can you help me? You can test it in Remix ide

Comment: no sorry i do not know

Comment: Oh, it's very bad :(